# Protractor: The .then after the getText() isn't executing

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, chai

The following method is passing a data table through and not executing the assertion and since it doesn't assert anything it automatically passes the cucumber step.

```
 Then(/^the following <fields> are displayed in the Method Information panel$/, (table) => {
    var hashes = table.hashes();
    var expectedValues: string[] = new Array();

    return hashes.forEach(function (hash) {
        console.log("In For Each");
        expectedValues.push(hash.fields);
        var index = expectedValues.length - 1;
        console.log(expectedValues[index])
        expectedValues[index] = expectedValues[index].replace(' ', '');

        return element(by.id("label" + expectedValues[index])).getText()
            .then(function (actualValues) {
                console.log("In Then:" + actualValues);
                report.takeScreenshot();
                return expecting(actualValues).to.deeply.equal(expectedValues[index]);
            }, function (err) {
                report.logError("An error occurred while comparing values." + err);
            });
    }, function (err) {
        report.logError("An error occurred while comparing values." + err);
    });
});
```

The console log looks like:

```
In For Each
Name
In For Each
Description
In For Each
Type
In For Each
Instrument System
  √ Then the following <fields> are displayed in the Method Information panel
  | fields            |
  | Name              |
  | Description       |
  | Type              |
  | Instrument System |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the return on the line :

```
return element(by.id("label" + expectedValues[index])).getText()
```

Does it continue with the then ?

I'm not familiar with TypeScript but do you also need to use return on the hashes ?

```
return hashes.forEach(function (hash) {
```

Instead of getText, do you get anything with

`getAttribute('textContent')`

or

`getAttribute('value')`

Comment: removed both returns and it still doesn't go into the then. I even removed each return individually and it still doesn't go into the then.

Comment: switching out the getText() didn't help

Comment: Are you sure **element(by.id("label" + expectedValues[index]))** locates anything ?

By the way, I never saw **expecting** instead of **expect**. Is it a cucumber thing? Also I wouldn't put a return on the expect. Is it necessary ?